# SELECT row if number included - SQL

Tags: php, sql, select

I am trying to select rows from a table called "blog" that have the correct department id.  The department_id field looks like '1,4,5'.  Now if Site number 1, 4 or 5 query they should get that post because their number is in that field.  But I am having trouble.  Here is my code so any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE draft = '1' AND department_id IN ($id) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: well, you say, you are trying to select rows from the table "blog", but that table is nowhere present in your sql query

Comment: Yes im sorry.  Its designed as a news script but I want it to work as a blog more so im changing my script.  thats the old database.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, you should be able to use the ISNUMERIC..
For example:
SELECT * FROM news WHERE ISNUMERIC(draft) = 1 AND department_id IN ($id) ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table is named `blog` or `news` ?

Let's say  `$id=3;`

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE draft = 1 AND $id IN (department_id) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Or You can also use

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE draft = 1 AND find_in_set('$id', cast(department_id as char)) > 0 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Looks like CSV is being stored in that field so `IN` might not work in this case?

Comment: I have done what you said but it still is not working...  The department id gives me "1,2,3" and the site id is "2".  So I thought about your code there and it is mine but backwards and I thought you were right but it didn't work :(

Comment: The code being excited is the one I posted with this question and the result it nothing... thats my issue.  I have 2 posts with a "2" in the department id and those do not appear.

Comment: But how to you run that query? need that PHP code which runs this query and grabs the result

Comment: '<?php
$post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE draft = '1' AND department_id IN ($id) ORDER BY id DESC") 
or die(mysql_error()); while($posts = mysql_fetch_array( $post )) { echo "blog.php?id=".$posts['id'].""; } ?>

Comment: You got it!  I just got your code to work!  You are my hero!  Thank you so much :))))

Comment: It wasn't working before because the query you posted in the comments above was wrong :)

Comment: Because you copied it wrong, your query is opposite of what I gave. Its not `department_id IN ($id)`, its `$id IN (department_id)`

Comment: Yes @Hanky 웃 Panky I know I copied it wrong but your first code did not work but the second one did.  So thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This will not scale well, but you can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE draft = '1' AND 
      (department_id = 1
      OR department_id = 4
      OR department_id = 5)
ORDER BY department_id DESC;
```

Comment: Nope wrong. `department_id` is not atomic, its a Comma separated string, this will not work.

Comment: exactly!  I have commas so I need to type it different or what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

What is $id? If $id is array you need make string for example

```
$id = array(1,4,5);
$ids = implode(',', $id);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE draft = '1' AND department_id IN ($ids) ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: Nope, its the other way round

Comment: department_id = 1,2,3